# Apache Felix obr deploy error messages

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, obr

How to read error messages when obr deploy command fails?
Here is an example:

```
 
-> obr deploy configuration-exporter
Unsatisfied requirement(s):
---------------------------
   (&(package=com.google.common.collect))
      RoutingService :: DAO
   (&(package=com.sybase365.routingservice))
      ARF :: Service Bundle :: Configuration Exporter
   (&(package=com.google.common.base))
      RoutingService :: DAO
   (service=org.osgi.service.event.EventHandler)
      Apache Felix EventAdmin
   (&(package=com.google.common.base))
      ARF :: Service Bundle :: Configuration Exporter
   (|(ee=J2SE-1.5))
      Guava: Google Core Libraries for Java 1.5
   (&(package=com.google.common.collect))
      ARF :: Service Bundle :: Configuration Exporter
   (service=org.osgi.service.event.EventHandler)
      Apache Felix EventAdmin
```

How to read the above message? What is actually unsatisfied?

Comment: Have you resolved your problem? I would be interested to know how you managed to fix it - and if my guess below was any good? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your obr is missing packages:

```
com.google.common.collect
com.sybase365.routingservice
com.google.common.base
com.google.common.base
com.google.common.collect
```

and then you probably don't have some services running:

```
org.osgi.service.event.EventHandler
```

and you probably don't have the required java-runtime:

```
J2SE-1.5
```

I usually take the first missing package - and try to resolve it. If it gets rid of that error, I keep going. If not - then something is wrong with your osgi runtime. Perhaps your are missing some bundles that it needs in order to do the deploy?

Comment: This is not correct. The error message says OBR cannot deploy the bundle because it cannot find the dependencies... but, at least in my case, the dependencies are all there and OBR is also printing this error message... Trying to figure out why.